# dojo rest target remote url

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo

I'm trying to call a remote web service with dojo the service seems working fine on the browser when I enter this url :

```
http://192.168.1.66:9080/RAD8JAX-RSWeb/jaxrs/customers/accounts/111-11-1111/
```

it returns :

```
[{"id":"001-111001","balance":12345.67},{"id":"001-111002","balance":6543.21},{"id":"001-111003","balance":98.76}]
```

I tryied to call it with dojo to show it in a data grid

```
dojo.require("dojo.store.JsonRest");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.ready(function(){
myStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"http://192.168.1.66:9080/RAD8JAX-RSWeb/jaxrs/customers/accounts/111-11-1111/"});
console.log(myStore);
 grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        store: dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
        structure: [
            {name:"ID", field:"id", width: "200px"},
            {name:"Balance", field:"balance", width: "200px"}
        ]
    }, "target-node-id"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
    grid.startup();
});


</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="target-node-id">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

should I make changes to my code Is the call is wrong or what?

I'm running the webservice on another machine and I have to run this page on the phone browser using phonegap so I have to call a remote url.
thx in advance

Comment: What errors do you get in the console ? Try to debug the jsonrest store first by printing out something like myStore.query("id='001-111001'").then(function(results){console.debug(results);}); It'll show you if your json rest store is correctly set.

Comment: Ah, you also you forgot to require dojo.data.ObjectStore

Comment: dojo.data.ObjectStore already set I did'nt sow it in my post

Answer (score 0):

try changing `myStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"http://192.168.1.66:9080/RAD8JAX-RSWeb/jaxrs/customers/accounts/111-11-1111/"});`

to `myStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"/RAD8JAX-RSWeb/jaxrs/customers/accounts/111-11-1111/"});`

this should help

if you don't get any javascript errors then it should work

the debugger is your friend :-)